# Undo for individual cells of QTableWidget in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTableWidget in my Main Window class.
I am unable to find a functionality which will undo the text change for the specified cell.
What I want to do is:

```
    void myCellUndoFunc(int row, int col)
    {
        table->item(row, col)->undo(); //table is my QTableWidget
    }
```

The problem is that there is no such undo().
So my question is, can there be a workaround for this problem using maybe some foo-doo combination of SIGNAL's & SLOT's?

Thanks!

PS: Please do not suggest to use Model/View framework because I have used QTableWidget extensively in my application. Sorry for the same.

Comment: This might get too memory intensive, but perhaps create a stack that stores the last state of a cell. If you want to undo just pop off the top stack value and set the cell to whatever is now on top.

Comment: @Muckle_ewe, that is what I am currently doing & not happy with it. That is why I asked this question :)

Comment: I see. Well in that case I'm not entirely sure how you could do it. Perhaps you know this already, but there is a QUndoStack class if you decide to go for the stack approach. It has an undo slot as well so you could use a signal slot approach with minimal extra coding. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qundostack.html

Comment: @Cool_Coder There's no magic in Qt which will do this for you automatically, so you will always end up keeping a stack of old values somewhere.  `QUndoStack` is the Qt way of doing this, although that might get expensive if you're keeping a separate stack for a lot of cells.  It also depends how much undo/redo history you want to maintain.

Comment: @Dan, as I mentioned I only want to have previous value so that if the value entered by the user is invalid (Ex: string instead of number), then I can reset the previous value instead of setting some default value. I am dealing with millions of cells hence the overload of back up copy for each cell is not feasible always, both processor wise & memory wise.

Comment: Unfortunately Qt does not have a way of applying a QDoubleValidator on a QTableWidgetItem, otherwise I would have used that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use the

```
void QTableWidgetItem::setData ( int role, const QVariant & value ) [virtual]
```

using the **Qt::UserRole** you are able to specify the last value. In your method u can access the previously set value with the data()-Method. The only thing you have to do is always keep the old value up-to-date.

Before you set the new value of the QTableWidgetItem

`tw->setData(Qt::UserRole, tw->text())`

and on undo u could than retrieve the data with

`tw->setText(tw->data(Qt::UserRole).toString())`

where "tw" is the current QTableWidgetItem using the contextmenu-event, the clicked-event or whatever u want. You could also subclass the QTableWidgetItem and handle this whole thing internally in your class, creating an undo()-method, storing the old value, etc.

Comment: I am not getting what you mean to say. Maybe you can show some code?

Comment: @Cool_Coder added an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: can you please explain which SIGNAL should be used for connecting to your SLOT? When cellchanged() is emitted the text of the item is already modified, so I cannot get the previous text.

Comment: Does the user directly edit a cell? Would be possible to react on the e.g. clickedevent and write ur own edit-method. Or subclass the QTableWidget and override the `void QTableWidget::editItem ( QTableWidgetItem * item )` method. Need more info on how the user is able to edit a cell or how the modification of the data in ur tablewidget is implemented

Comment: The table is edited by user just like in MS Excel. Currently I am maintaining a QList <QList <QString *> *> *myCell in dynamic memory which basically stores the latest valid values for each cell. I have create my own SLOT which is connected to the cellChanged() SIGNAL of tw. Now what this SLOT does is checks whether the value from QTableWidgetItem is valid or not. If valid, I am updating this value into corresponding myCell. If not then discard this new value, take value from myCell & set it to QTableWidgetItem. All this mechanism sort of my own QDoubleValidator. Anything else?